# If $\overline{k}$ is an algebraic closure of a field $k$, then $\overline{k}[x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}]$ is integral over $k[x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I want to prove that if $\overline{k}$ is an algebraic closure of a field $k$, then $\overline{k}[x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}]$ is integral over $k[x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}]$.

It is used in exercise 11.3 of the book *Introduction to commutative algebra* by Atiyah-McDonald. I think the easiest way to prove is to show that, if $f\in\overline{k}[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}]$, then $k[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}][f]$ is a finitely generated $k[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}]$-module, but I do not know how to prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, show that if $R \to S$ is integral and $R \to T$ is arbitrary, then $T \to T \otimes_R S$ is integral. Prove this by using the fact $(*)$ that integral elements form a subring.

Apply this to $k \to \overline{k}$ and $k \to k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$. Of course, a direct proof without tensor products is also possible; but in any case I would just use the fact $(*)$.